# How to analyse the communication between a WebApp loaded with awesomium and the native program?

Tags: javascript

I have a Windows program that uses [awesomium](http://www.awesomium.com/) to display a WebApp. This WebApp communicates in some way with the client program through some native calls. I found references to `window.externalHost` and `window.native` in the JS source, but it's build with [YUI](http://yuilibrary.com) and has tens of thousand lines of code and single character variables and I can't quite figure out what exactly they are doing (static analysis).

I have injected Javascript into the WebApp to check those two objects:

```
try {
    document.write(JSON.stringify(window.externalHost, null, 4))
} catch (err) {
    document.write(err)
}
```

But `window.externalHost` is `undefined` and `window.native` is `{}`.

So my questions are:

- How are native calls usually set up?
- What interfaces do exist and how are they used? (Both directions)
- Can I "detour"/"intercept" native calls to see what they are sending?
- Are there any remote JS debug projects which I could inject to dynamically debug the complex WebApp?

---

**update 1:** I am confident that it uses `window.native`. Because of this Object `{}`. It seems likely that the communication is not implemented as `window.externalHost.postMessage()` based on what I have read on the [awesomium wiki](http://wiki.awesomium.com/general-use/introduction-to-javascript-integration.html).

I now try to capture what methods are called on it. My idea was to overwrite `window.onerror` to capture all errors and set `window.native = undefined;` to capture exceptions like `Cannot call aNativeCall() on undefined`. Unfortunately it seems that `windows.native` can't be overwritten - it doesn't stay undefined.

Any other ideas?

---

**update 2:**

I came up with this javascript code to check some interesting Objects like `window.external`, etc...

```
obj = ['external', 'externalHost', 'native', 'Y', ['Y','native'],['Y','Native'], ['Y','external'], ['Y','externalHost']];
for(i=0; i< obj.length; ++i) {
    try {

        if(obj[i] instanceof Array) {
            var tmp = window[obj[i][0]];
            for(j=1; j<obj[i].length; ++j) {
                tmp = tmp[obj[i][j]]
            }
            document.write(obj[i]+" | <b>"+Object.getOwnPropertyNames(tmp)+"</b><br>");
        } else {
            document.write(obj[i]+" | <b>"+Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window[obj[i]])+"</b><br>");
        }

    } catch(err) {
        document.write(obj[i]+" | <i>Error: "+err+"</i><br>");
    }
}
```

It became slowly more clear that it has to be `window.native`. This object has the following properties: 'on','isNative','scale','Emitter','call','register','_ready'

When I try to call `window.native.call()` the native program crashes. And the debug information shows that it crashed in a `ProcessRequest` function. So I found the right interface.

I now need to find out how exactly this interface is used. Unfortunately I can't overwrite `window.native.call = function() { ... }` to log the calls.

Anybody another idea?